# c++11 what is first? constructor or default value?

Tags: c++11, constructor, initialization

In c++11 you can do this:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo();
        bool test = false;
};

Foo::Foo()
{
    // is test guaranteed to be false now? and is it surely not overriden later?
    this->test = true;
}
```

what I want to know is basically described in comments, I can verify this with my compiler, but is this mentioned in standard? Is it always same on all platforms and all compilers?

Comment: It's as if you wrote `Foo(): test(false) { this->test = true; }`

Comment: So, you mean that the default value is first and it is later overriden in constructor which is the final value?

Comment: Exactly. If you want to **initialize** `test` with another value, rather than initializing it to false and then assigning true to it, use the initialization list as usual: `Foo(string s) : test{true} {}`, `Foo(bool b) : test{b} {}`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is test guaranteed to be false now? Yes.

is it surely not overriden later? It will not be overriden. The default is set as part of the initializer list at the start of the constructor.

If test is not included in the initializer list the compiler will put it in with the default. For your constructor the compiler would actually generate code for this:

```
Foo::Foo()
    : test(false)
{
    // is test guaranteed to be false now?
    this->test = true;
    // is it surely not overriden later?
}
```

With this constructor test would first be initialized to false and then later in the body set to true.

If you had written:

```
Foo::Foo()
    : test(true)
{
}
```

The test would be in the initialiser list already and the compiler won't put it there and test would be directly initialized to true.

Comment: The compiler is surely allowed to optimize the initialization avoiding the two assignments...

Comment: Yes it is but we should also consider what happens in more complex code where `this->test = true;` might have been inside an if statement for instance.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11, there are three places a non-static data member can be initialized:

- in the body of the class (a *brace-or-equal-initializer*)
- in the list of members before the constructor body (a *mem-initializer*)
- within the constructor body.

If a non-static data member has both a *brace-or-equal-initializer* and a *mem-initializer*, then the *mem-initializer* overrides the *brace-or-equal-initializer*; this is specified in 12.6.2.p9.

In either case, the initialization of the non-static data member occurs before the body of the constructor is entered, whereupon the constructor can alter the value of the member.

Answer (score 2):

From [*class.base.init*] **12.6.2 - Initializing bases and members**

> **9** If a given non-static data member has both a *brace-or-equal-initializer* and
>   a *mem-initializer*, the initialization specified by the mem-initializer is performed,
>   and the non-static data member’s *brace-or-equal-initializer* is ignored.

Example

```
struct A
{
  int i = /∗ some integer expression with side effects ∗/ ;
  A(int arg) : i(arg) { } // ...
};
```

the `A(int)` constructor will simply initialize `i` to the value of `arg`, and the side effects in `i`'s *brace-or-equal-initializer* will not take place.

> **10** In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following
>   order:
>
> - First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class (1.8),
>     virtual base classes are initialized in the order they appear on a depth-first
>     left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes, where
>     “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the base classes in the derived class
>     *base-specifier-list*.
> - Then, direct base classes are initialized in declaration order as they
>     appear in the *base-specifier-list* (regardless of the order of the
>     *mem-initializers*).
> - Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in
>     the class definition (again regardless of the order of the *mem-initializers*).
> - Finally, the compound-statement of the constructor body is executed.

So

```
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo();
  bool test = false;
};

Foo::Foo()
{
  // is test guaranteed to be false now? and is it surely not overriden later?
  this->test = true;
}
```

`test` is guaranteed to be `false` and it won't be overwritten (*"Finally, the compound-statement of the constructor body is executed"*)